# Vb.net Using child instance in a parent-typed variable

Tags: .net, vb.net, class, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm more familiar with how Java does polymorphism so I might be doing it wrong in vb

I'm trying use polymorphism and inheritance to have one instance that can take on multiple forms,
the issue is the variable is instantiated as the parent type and initialized as a child class instance but I can't access the child properties.

below is an example what i'm trying to do:

```
sub main()
  Dim animal as Animal           'instantiated as parent type
  'some code later
  animal= New Dog()              'no problems here
  dim legs = animal.legs         'this works
  dim fur = animal.fur           'this is an error 
end sub

Public Class Animal
  Property legs as integer
End Class 

Public Class Dog
  inherits Animal
  Property fur as Boolean = True
End Class
```

It would be great if i could get this to work.

Comment: I see that now but I was looking for something like 'dim animal as Object' and then I can do 'animal = New Dog()' and it will become a Dog class type which I believe Java does. stupid Java spoiling me.

Comment: As Object works in this case and it doesn't cause an error, I will just need to be more careful. I want it to be able to take on multiple forms because it will be in a object that will either have a 'cat' or 'dog' but not both, i.e. Class Kennel with a property for class type animal

Answer (score 1):

This is actually declaring, not instantiating.

`Dim animal as Animal`

And if you know it is an animal, then create it as one like so:

`Dim doggo As New Dog`

The only time you should need to treat the `Dog` as an `Animal` is if you are performing something on it's `Legs`.

For example (in the `Animal` class):

```
Shared Sub AmputateLeg(patient As Animal)
    patient.Legs = patient.Legs - 1
End Sub
```

That you can call from `Dog` like so:

```
Dim doggo As New Dog()
doggo.Legs = 4
Animal.AmputateLeg(doggo)
Console.WriteLine(doggo.Legs) ' Shows 3.
```

As Plutonix commented, a base class should not know anything about the derived class, hence the IDE can't locate the `Fur` property when the `Dog` is treated as an `Animal` type

Perhaps you want something along the lines of an `Interface` instead

```
Public Interface IAnimal
    Property Fur As Boolean
    Property Legs As Integer
End Interface

Public Class Dog
    Implements IAnimal

    Public Property Fur As Boolean = True Implements IAnimal.Fur
    Public Property Legs As Integer = 4 Implements IAnimal.Legs
End Class

Public Class Duck
    Implements IAnimal

    Public Property Fur As Boolean = False Implements IAnimal.Fur
    Public Property Legs As Integer = 2 Implements IAnimal.Legs
End Class
```

Using an `Interface` this way means that you can always refer to `Legs` and `Fur` of any animal.

Comment: @Plutonix i'm not sure what you mean, could you give an example? this is probably the approach i'm looking for.

Comment: I'm looking for a way where I can declare a variable/container and have similar classes fit into that container. So that later I will have some logic that will do different things depending on what's in it. 

At the moment it looks likes my best approach would be to forget inheritance and keeping all the properties in one class 'Animal' and just check a property called 'animalSpecies' to determine what i need to do with it.

Comment: "Similar classes" suggests Inheritance or an Interface and doesnt rule out knowing what they are.  Both are intended to do "different things depending* on the type.  `Dog.Speak()` would be totally different code than `Cat.Speak()` @pulse  Sans inheritance you have gobs of If code blocks to do different things

Comment: the 'different things' being done is done by a different class altogether, something like a groomer or caretaker, the cat and dog class will only contain property, no methods. so if species=dog, groomer does these things, if species = cat then do this, etc.

Comment: Then you could give the Base or Interface a Groom method, that the Dog class either Overrides/Implements.